# Page Template CSS file not loading

Tags: page-template

I have created a php file and in that file `include 'practice.html';` I am including a html file.
In the HTML file I have a few CSS files linked.

But When I upload the page template (`php file`) I only get the HTML file.

It is not able to link the css files linked to the Html file.

PS : All my HTML, CSS and PHP files are stored under the theme folder of my wordpress.

How can I possibly link the css files?

Comment: What is your CSS Path and do you get any console errors?

Comment: It is it in the same folder as mentioned above. And no errors, just the simple HTML page is shown.

Comment: What do the css file urls look like when you view source of the page once you upload the php file?  WP doesn't do relative urls, only absolute, so your paths to the css files may be wrong.